# Please help me identify these statues

Tags: identification-request

My friend took a few pictures of what appears to be a Hindu goddess and asked my help to identify them. Unfortunately, I am unable to definitively say who they are. My first guess was Lakshmi or Parvati but I don't think that's correct.

[image: A dancing statue next to a statue of Buddha.]
[image: Another statue in a dancing pose.]

I do not have these images in higher resolution. I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry if these are not Hindu goddesses. I don't mean any disrespect.

Comment: I think Shiva -Parvati in their respective dance postures (Tandavam and Lasya).

Comment: The first picture (You can see the snake tail in his left hand) is Krsna dancing on Kaliya. As you said the second can be either Parvati or Lakshmi but I'm leaning towards Lakshmi because of the flower like thing in her hand and her general posture.

Comment: @Surya notice bare body female I don't think she is any Godess.

Comment: @Yogi Actually such depictions are common in many sculptures of Devi.

Comment: @Surya Okay but don't you think this is disgusting?

Comment: @Yogi It is not disgusting if you look at it as the *artistic depiction* of the great beauty of Devi which has been extolled most excellently by Adi Shankaracharya in his Saundarya Lahari, and many other saints.

Comment: @TheDestroyer you may post answer :)